# How send error firebase message from service to controller?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I use Angular js and firebase.
For my login form and my register form, i have a controller "userController" who call function in userProvider, my service.

I want to show the firebase error message in my view. How my provider can send message to my controller ?

My code :

userController.js :

```js
$scope.login = function(user){
            userProvider.login(user);
 }
```

userProvider.js :

```js
this.login = function(user){
    Auth.$authWithPassword({//on connecte l'utilisateur
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    }).then(function(authData) {
        console.log("Utilisateur connecté:", authData.uid);
        $location.path('#/profil');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Echec connexion:", error);
        // I want return the error.code for use it in my controller
    });
 }
```

login.html :

```html
<form ng-hide="authData" class="form-signin col-md-6" name="loginForm" novalidate >
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Connexion</h2>
<p style="color:red;" ng-show="userDataError">{{userDataErrorMessage}}</p>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : loginForm.email.$invalid }">
    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email"  class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="user.email" name="email" ng-required autofocus>
    <p class="help-block text-error" ng-show="loginForm.email.$invalid">Cet email n'est pas valide</p>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : loginForm.password.$invalid }">
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="8" name="password" ng-required>
    <p class="help-block text-warning" ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.minlength" >Minimum 8 caractères</p>
</div>
<button  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="login(user)">Connexion</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **chain** from the function, **return** the derived promise.

```
this.login = function(user){
    //return promise
    return derivedPromise = (
        Auth.$authWithPassword({//on connecte l'utilisateur
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password
        }).then(function(authData) {
            console.log("Utilisateur connecté:", authData.uid);
            $location.path('#/profil');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Echec connexion:", error);
            //throw error to chain
            throw error;
        });
    );
});
```

In the controller, use the promise to display the error.

```
$scope.login = function(user){
     userProvider.login(user)
         .catch( function onRejected(error) {
              $scope.errorMessage = ("Echec connexion:" + error);
         });
};
```

By **returning** the promise, results (either fulfilled or rejected) can be retrieved by using the `.then` or `.catch` methods of the promise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all for these kinds of plans i would defintely not use a provider but a service... So what you can do to achieve your problem about showing the error to the controller is:

In loginService.js

```
app.service('loginService', ["$scope", "Auth", "$firebaseAuth", function($scope,Auth,$firebaseAuth){
  var vm= this;
  this.login = function(user){
    Auth.$authWithPassword({//on connecte l'utilisateur
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    })
 }
}])
```

and in the Ctrl:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
loginService.login().then(function(authData) {
        console.log("Utilisateur connecté:", authData.uid);
        $scope.userData = authData.uid;
        $location.path('#/profil');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Echec connexion:", error);
         $scope.errorLogin = error;
        // I want return the error.code for use it in my controller
        $scope.loginError = error;
    });;

})
```

Comment: When I use this code I have a console error :  angular.js:13294 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.login (userController.js:15)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (angular.js:14138), <anonymous>:4:299)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15151)
    at callback (angular.js:24674)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16895)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16995)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:24679)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3417)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3405)

Comment: Ok @cecilecemoi you know what would be best! If you can show us your code in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/)!

Comment: Sorry @cecilecemoi that was my previous version.. Look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/JJQDmseLRpypROoaGbLH?p=preview

Comment: i don't see the modifications

Comment: The Authentication $authWithPassword now logs.. @cecilecemoi

Comment: Ok @cecilecemoi now login with a invalid user here: http://plnkr.co/edit/JJQDmseLRpypROoaGbLH?p=preview

Comment: I think something wrong I see the same code that I sent you, and so I have the same error in console : Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: No i dont see that @cecilecemoi . Ima upload a quick viedo to prove it